# Get hourly data based on StartDate

Tags: sql

For Example,

I had data something like this :-

```
batch  MIN    MAX   TIME
 X      10     20   2018-07-12 10:29:00.000
 X      30     50   2018-07-12 10:30:00.000
 X      50     30   2018-07-12 10:31:00.000
 |      |       |     | 
 X      40     20   2018-07-12 11:45:00.000
```

Now I want hourly data based on start time, For example :-

```
DURATION                                             MIN
2018-07-12 10:29:00.000-2018-07-12 11:29:00.000      10
2018-07-12 11:30:00.000-2018-07-12 12:30:00.000      10
```

How can I get this?(Get Min Value For every hour based on Start Time)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Where do you get the output? The data isn't in the sample data. As posted this just doesn't make much sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

dateadd function allows you to add or subtract days,hours, minutes to a date.

Consider The below query

```
select dateadd(HOUR, -1, getdate()) as time_added, 
       getdate() as curr_date
```

The -1 is for subtracting one hour (adding negative one hour)

The result of above query is :

```
timeadded                   curr_date

2018-07-12 13:25:31.603   2018-07-12 14:25:31.603
```

Instead of getdate() use your startdate

In your case it would be

```
select min from table where time<@starttime and time> dateadd(HOUR, -1, @starttime)
```